# Node MongoDB driver strange callback on Save

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am writing a small helper module to make the nodejs mongodb driver work with promises.  One of my functions is as follows:

```
this.saveP = function(doc,options){
    return new Promise(function(res,rej){
        collection.save(doc,options,function(err,result){
            if(err) rej(err);
            else res(result);
        })
    })
}
```

But when I call this function the promise resolves with a strange object:

```
{ result: { ok: 1, nModified: 1, n: 1 },
  connection:
   { domain: null,
     _events:
      { close: [Object],
        error: [Object],
        timeout: [Object],
        parseError: [Object],
        connect: [Function] },
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     options:
      { socketOptions: {},
        auto_reconnect: true,
        ...
```

The documentation (http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#save) seems to indicate that this should work.  Whats going on?

Comment: Looks like it is working fine. Why is it strange?

Comment: The promise should resolve with the original document upon a successful save.  So this.saveP({_id:...,test:"hello"}) should resolve with {_id:...,test:"hello"}

Comment: No. check the documentation callback [result](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#~WriteOpResult) type. It doesn't return the document